# Not posting events in Flurry ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am creating custom events of Flurry and want to show in my Flurry .But it is not showing anything.I am getting some logs but is difficult to understand.I read some links related to that,where they told to wait for 7-8 hours.I download the SDK Flurry iPhone SDK vi Phone 5.4.0.zip where i attached Flurry.h and libFlurry_5.4.0.a .I also link libFlurry_5.4.0.a with Link with binary Libraries.

**This is my code:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry startSession:@""];
    [Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSDictionary *articleParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"John Q", @"Author",
                               @"Registered", @"User_Status",
                               nil];
    [Flurry logEvent:@"Article_Read" withParameters:articleParams];
}
```

**This is the response i am getting:**

```
Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_140_5.4.0] 
FlurrySession: Set userID[(null)]
FlurrySession: Add session with startTime[2014-10-10 05:50:42 +0000] to saved sessions

FlurrySession: Add crashed former session
FlurrySession: Event logging enabled[1]
FlurrySession: Session reports on close enabled[1]
FlurrySession: Session reports on pause enabled[0]
FlurrySession: Crash reporting enabled[0]
FlurrySession: Initialized session from scratch with startTime[2014-10-10 06:07:22 +0000]
FlurrySession: Created active session with API[]
FlurrySession: Session reports on close enabled[1]
FlurrySession: Session reports on pause enabled[1]
FlurrySession: Event logging enabled[1]
FlurrySession: Crash reporting enabled[1]
FlurrySession: Sending sessions to server, include current NO
FlurrySession: Initial timestamp[2014-10-10 05:36:41 +0000] from secure source
Flurry: start background task
FlurrySession: Scheduled send 1 session(s).
FlurrySession: dealloc session
FlurrySession: Attempting to record Event eventName[Article_Read] with parameters[{
Author = "John Q";
"User_Status" = Registered;
}]
FlurrySession: Event count for eventName[Article_Read] updated to count[1]
FlurrySession: Recording event eventName[Article_Read] with parameters[{
Author = "John Q";
"User_Status" = Registered;
}] complete

updated network status [1] ======== 
FlurrySession: networkStatusChanged to  reachable
Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response[<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7b36d8a0>
 { 
     URL: http://data.flurry.com/aas.do 
 }
 { 
     status code: 200, headers
     {
         Connection = "keep-alive";
         "Content-Length" = 122;
         "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
         Date = "Fri, 10 Oct 2014 06:04:58 GMT";
         Server = nginx;
         Via = "ICAP/1.0 gsfw (C-ICAP/0.1.7 Gaj Engine service )";
         "X-Cache" = "MISS from localhost";
     } 
}]
FlurrySession: async http response code: 200, id [0FDA7F67-FBB6-472E-B16A-E5EE13161441]
-[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/rajat/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/48F3DD04-8A7B-4009-BC46-4202F77526B6/data/Containers/Data/Application/4CF74646-2DC8-4DAE-8BDC-78F4201DE181/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryPropertiesData509492151_140.archive
-[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/rajat/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/48F3DD04-8A7B-4009-BC46-4202F77526B6/data/Containers/Data/Application/4CF74646-2DC8-4DAE-8BDC-78F4201DE181/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryCkData509492151_140.archive
Flurry: stop background task
```

Please check the response whether is fine or i have to wait for some time.

Comment: Yes everything is fine. Wait for some time and check.

Comment: How to know whether response is fine or not and how much time it will take.

Comment: And i am getting Set userID[(null)] in log.what userid i have to set.

Comment: FlurrySession: Created active session with API[] is this empty?

Comment: No i removed my application key from there

Comment: see my response.below

Answer (score 0):

This is response for successfull ads.i am getting this response also i am getting ads

> ```
> Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_118_4.2.3] 
> FlurrySession: Initialized session from scratch with startTime[2014-10-10 06:39:46 +0000]
> FlurrySession: Created active session with API[XXXXXXXXXX]
> FlurrySession: Session reports on close enabled[1]
> FlurrySession: Session reports on pause enabled[1]
> FlurrySession: Event logging enabled[1]
> FlurrySession: Crash reporting enabled[1]
> FlurrySession: Sending sessions to server, include current NO
> FlurrySession: Initial timestamp[2014-10-10 06:39:46 +0000] created and saved
> Flurry: start background task
> FlurrySession: Scheduled send 0 session(s).
> FlurrySession: Attempting to record Event eventName[App Started] with parameters[(null)]
> FlurrySession: Event count for eventName[App Started] updated to count[1]
> FlurrySession: Recording event eventName[App Started] with parameters[(null)] complete
> Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response[<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xcc8ebd0> { URL: http://data.flurry.com/aas.do } { status code: 200, headers {
> Connection = close;
> "Content-Length" = 0;
> "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
> Date = "Fri, 10 Oct 2014 06:23:44 GMT";
> Server = nginx;
> } }]
>  FlurrySession: async http response code: 200, id [997E1D0C-39B4-4F75-9F67-2003F4DDE4CC]
> ```

Comment: What to set UserId in Flurry.Please tell me.Whenevr i set userid it will show error in Event logs.

Comment: you forgot the line  [Flurry startSession:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX"];

Comment: [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry startSession:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX"];
    [FlurryAds initialize:_window.rootViewController];
     [Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES];   userid from flurryads app related
    [Flurry logEvent:@"App Started"];

Comment: is that userID is in active?you will get user id back once you request to ther server.